# Одинаковые элементы <vector>

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как быстро узнать, есть ли в векторе одинаковые элементы?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть стандартный метод [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

А еще можно так:

```
set<int> s;
unsigned size = vec.size();
for( unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i ) s.insert( vec[i] );
vec.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

И так:

```
set<int> s( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
vec.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

Если количество дубликатов большое, то в плане производительность вариант с std:set будет производительнее.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм с вычислительной сложностью *O(n²)*:

```
template<typename T> bool hasDuplicate(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = i+1; j < v.size(); ++j)
            if (v[i] == v[j])
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Достоинство в нетребовательности к памяти, недостаток - медленный.

Алгоритм с вычислительной сложностью *O(n)*:

```
template <typename T> bool isDuplicate(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value);

    bool* flags = new bool[1 << (8*sizeof(T))]();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (flags[v[i]])
            return true;
        flags[v[i]] = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Достоинство в быстроте вычислений, недостаток - огромный объём требуемой памяти.

Comment: прям таки огромный?

Comment: @АнтонСазонов Берём `T=int`. Сейчас `int` обычно 32 бита. Нужно будет `2^32` элемента типа `bool`. Это минимум 4Gb (а может быть и больше, если `bool` не однобайтовый). Даже если работать с битами и то нужно будет 512Mb. Для тупой проверки на уникальность это просто огромный объём.

Comment: Если использовать vector<bool>, то расход памяти можно сократить в 8 раз (ну или сколько там на 1 bool). А вообще, если уж память использовать, то дублировать, сортировать и за O(n) пробегаться. Т.е. в общем, такой алгоритм потребует O(n log n) на вычисления и O(n) на память либо O(1) если допускается модификация исходного контейнера.

Answer (score 1):

Если под словом "быстро" вы имеете в виду компактную запись, позволяющую определить, есть ли в векторе дублирующиеся значения, не меняя при этом сам вектор и порядок следования его элементов, то сделать это можно в одну строчку:

```
if ( std::set<int>( v.begin(), v.end() ).size() != v.size() ) { /*...*/ }
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve( N );

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ), N, [=] { return std::rand() % N; } );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if ( std::set<int>( v.begin(), v.end() ).size() != v.size() )
    {
        std::cout << "The vector has duplicates" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The vector contains unique values" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
3 2 1 4 6 9 1 9 7 2 
The vector has duplicates
```

Действительно, как видно из вывода, числа 1, 2 и 9 дублируются.

Если же вам разрешается отсортировать вектор, то определить, есть ли в векторе дублирующиеся элементы, проще всего с использование алгоритма `std::adjacent_find`.

Вот демонстрационная программа, показывающая данный подход:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve( N );

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ), N, [=] { return std::rand() % N; } );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if ( std::adjacent_find( v.begin(), v.end() ) != v.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "The vector has duplicates" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The vector contains unique values" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может выглядеть, к примеру, следующим образом:

```
2 7 8 3 4 8 9 2 5 2 
2 2 2 3 4 5 7 8 8 9 
The vector has duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

Отсортировать и пройтись вдоль вектора